# How to detect @ in keydown or keypress in jquery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to use the keypress or keydown event on '@' to generate a dropdown on a contenteditale  div. But I didnot find the key code for '@' and i cannot use shift and 2 beacause it will be problem for many keyboard layout including mobile keyboard layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for the keycode for @ which is decimal `64` in jQuery's `e.which`:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e) {
    // look for @ key
    if (e.which === 64) {
        alert("@ key pressed");
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s7KGb/

---

You could also code it like this which might be a bit more readable:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(e) {
    // look for @ key
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) === '@') {
        alert("@ key pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: A side note: `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` would return the exact character. PS: is it jQuery's `which` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.which ?

Comment: @zerkms - jQuery normalizes browser differences between `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode` and puts a consistent result in `event.which`.  See the jQuery description [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).  It may also be something that some versions of Firefox do, but it is not part of any standard and is certainly not something you can use in all browsers without an intermediary like jQuery.

Comment: +1 Too simple, I thought it would be something like `e.shiftKey && e.which == 50`